# How to select 2 different attributes from an event in Drools

Tags: java, drools, complex-event-processing

I am trying to write a drools rule that check if two events happens from the same stream. I have a compliance rules class which contains logic (in the working memory) to be compared with events coming from entry point. all I need is to detect the occurrence of two events, for example I want to detect that event A occurred and after that B occurred. I wrote this role in drools syntax

```
$comrule : Comprules ( pattern == "response" , isBefore == false)  
Event  (task == $comrule.antecedent) from entry-point StoreOne  
Event (task == $comrule.consequent) from entry-point StoreOne
```

the problem is this technique doesn't work. the only one working is when I wrote this

```
Event  (task == $comrule.antecedent) from entry-point StoreOne  
not Event (task == $comrule.consequent) from entry-point StoreOne
```

I read the drools documentation but I couldn't find any solve to this problem
any help will be appreciated

Comment: It's impossible to tell why you don't get the expected result. You need to provide a complete example. -- Did you insert two `Event` facts with the proper values for `task` and were they in Working Memory at the same time? If the second version of the patterns fires you have inserted the first one but not yet the second one.

Comment: this is the input I inserted  
         insertEvent(entryPointStoreOne, new Event(), "X","8");
         insertEvent(entryPointStoreOne, new Event(), "Y","9");  Comprules cr4 = new Comprules();
         cr4.setpattern("response");
         cr4.setantecedent("X");
         cr4.setconsequent("Y");
         cr4.setanttimestamp(3);
         cr4.setconsimesptamp(4);
         cr4.settimespan(2);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical pattern for checking that two Events occur in the right order is this:

```
Comprules( pattern == "response", !isBefore, $a: antecedent, $b: consequent )
$one: Event( task == $a ) from entry-point StoreOne  
$two: Event( task == $b, this after $one ) from entry-point StoreOne
```

Using `not` tests for the absence of a fact, which would be the situation after `$one` has arrived while `$two` still is absent.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I think this is the logic I wanted as I need to process the stream of events and catch two events from the same stream I could do this already in ESPER but it a little hard om drools.

Comment: I tried this code but it isn't working. this is the typical input I used..for the facts in the working memory (in our case the compliance rules class)  
`Comprules cr4 = new Comprules();
cr4.setpattern("response");
cr4.setantecedent("X");
cr4.setconsequent("Y");` 
for the events coming from the stream 
`insertEvent(entryPointStoreOne, new Event(), "X","8");
insertEvent(entryPointStoreOne, new Event(), "Y","9");`  
it should work as if Y occured after X the rule should be fired

Comment: That's insufficient for determining why it does not work. Which parameters did you use for creating the session? What's the timestamp of your events? Which clock do you use?

Comment: I didn't use any clocks my code uses 2 classes: event and comp rule class and I used the streaming mode. I am a beginner in drools and I think I have something missing in the code but I don't know what is it. I can send you the full version of the code to check it but how can I attach it here ?

Comment: Not using a pseudo-clock may cause problems if you don't insert fact in realtime. Streaming mode is OK, but you still need to manipulate the session clock as  a pseudo clock so that time stamps are useful. -- You should be able to reduce everything so that it can be added to your question.

Comment: The Drools manual contains enough: select the right option, advance the clock manually between insert and other method calls.

Comment: I tried the pseudo clock and it worked. thanks @laune for your advice :)